# How do you prevent Liberty from deleting the expanded folder after a restart

Tags: web-applications, war, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

my server.xml has

< applicationManager autoExpand="true" / >

...

 < application context-root="BaseX" id="BaseX" name="BaseX" type="war" location="C:\Program Files\BaseX.war" / >

when I start the application

> server start myapp

the whole expanded folder is deleted and recreated.
WebSphere\Liberty\usr\servers\myapp\apps\expanded\BaseX.war

since BaseX.war is my database i loose all the data with it after a simple re-start (stop and start)

Comment: Are you changing the war file between the restarts?

Comment: no ..same BaseX.war

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve this right now is to deploy your application as an expanded WAR rather than as an archive. Instead of the WAR archive c:\Program Files\BaseX.war, you would have a directory c:\Program Files\BaseX.war that contains the expanded BaseX.war file. In this case, the application would run directly from that directory and would not be expanded into apps/expanded.

You could also turn off expansion of applications by setting autoExpand to false on the applicationManager element, but that's likely not a good solution for you because you're writing directly to the application. If you followed this path, you would probably need to change the application to write data to a different location.

Comment: are you saying to expand BaseX.war into another directory/folder? is there something to do on server.xml for this?

Comment: Nothing has to change in server.xml -- the application location can be either an archive file or an expanded directory. You wouldn't expand BaseX.war into another directory, but rather into a directory named BaseX.war (so you would have c:\program files\BaseX.war\WEB-INF\web.xml , etc, not c:\program files\BaseX.war\BaseX.war\WEB-INF\web.xml )

Comment: I tried the following and it worked <br/> 1. unzip BaseX.war into a folder
   C:\Program Files\BaseX
2. set server.xml not to expand and point to this new folder
<applicationManager autoExpand="false" />
<application context-root="BaseX" id="BaseX" name="BaseX" type="war" location="C:\Program Files\BaseX" />

start and stop of the server do not delete the whole data

Comment: do i need to call it BaseX.war? this deleting of the expanded folder seems like a bug to me...is there a way to stop it? why is it happening with a simple restart?

Comment: The directory can be anything as long as you have 'type="war"' -- otherwise it would need the '.war' extension on the directory to figure out that it's a web application.

Comment: There isn't currently a way to prevent the refresh of the expanded directory on server start. It's possible this may change in the future, but best practice would still be to avoid writing data directly to application binaries (otherwise, any update to the binaries would result in deleting the existing data.)